# Hibernate. Декартово произведение при загрузке коллекции

Tags: java, hibernate

Пытаюсь разобраться со стратегией наследования "table per subclass" в Hibernate (5.2.2).

Классы с мапппингом (геттеры и сеттеры не указаны для компактности):

```
//Класс, содержащий поля, общие для всех классов
@MappedSuperclass
public class DBObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Integer id;

    @Column(name = "correctdt")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date correctDate;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (o != null && (o instanceof DBObject)) {
            DBObject oo = (DBObject) o;
            if (id != null) {
                result = id.equals(oo.id);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (id != null) ? id.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}


//Класс, содержащий коллекцию элементов с наследованием.
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "tmp_test_class")
public class TestClass extends DBObject implements Serializable{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "testClass")
    protected Collection<TestParent> tests = new ArrayList<>();
}


//Родительский класс
@Entity
@Table(name = "tmp_test_parent")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class TestParent extends DBObject implements Serializable{
    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "test_id")
    protected TestClass testClass;
}


//Подкласс
@Entity
@Table(name = "tmp_test_child1")
public class TestChild extends TestParent{
    @Column
    private String field1;
}
```

Коллекция tests из класса TestClass должна загружаться из базы только в момент обращения к ней (Lazy loading).

Но при попытке обращения к коллекции формируется некорректный sql-запрос с декартовым произведением, в котором таблицы tmp_test_parent и tmp_test_class не связаны:

```
SELECT tests0_.test_id AS test_id4_2_0_,
  tests0_.id           AS id1_2_0_,
  tests0_.id           AS id1_2_1_,
  tests0_.correctdt    AS correctdt2_2_1_,
  tests0_.name         AS name3_2_1_,
  tests0_.test_id      AS test_id4_2_1_,
  tests0_1_.field1     AS field1_0_1_,
  CASE
    WHEN tests0_1_.id IS NOT NULL
    THEN 1
    WHEN tests0_.id IS NOT NULL
    THEN 0
  END AS clazz_1_
FROM tmp_test_parent tests0_,
  tmp_test_child1 tests0_1_
WHERE tests0_.test_id=?
```

На самом деле там должен быть LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Если у коллекции выставить FetchType = EAGER, то всё работает как надо. Но мне в абсолютном большинстве случаев сразу грузить эту коллекцию не нужно.

```
//Класс для тестирования
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        //Грузим класс с коллекцией
        TestClass test = session.get(TestClass.class, 1);
        Collection<TestParent> tests = test.getTests();

        System.out.println(tests.size()); //Из-за декартова произведения результат неверен

        //Грузим те же объекты напрямую
        Collection<TestParent> tests2 = session.createCriteria(TestParent.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("testClass.id", 1))
                .list();

        System.out.println(tests2.size()); //А тут всё верно
    }
}
```

Вот что хранится в базе:
Таблица tmp_test_parent (3 записи)

```
"ID"    "NAME"  "TEST_ID"   "CORRECTDT"
  1      "11"       1       14.09.16 12:31:40
  2      "22"       1       21.09.16 12:31:46
  3      "33"       1       21.09.16 12:31:51
```

Таблица tmp_test_child (2 записи)

```
"ID"    "FIELD1"    "CORRECTDT"
 1          111     21.09.16 12:32:26
 3          333     21.09.16 12:32:28
```

Вот что получилось после загрузки:

```
TestClass{
    tests=[
        TestChild{
            name=11, 
            field1=111
        }, 
        TestChild{
            name=22, 
            field1=111
        }, 
        TestChild{
            name=33, 
            field1=111
        }, 
        TestChild{
            name=11, 
            field1=111
        }, 
        TestChild{
            name=22, 
            field1=111
        }, 
        TestChild{
            name=33, 
            field1=111
        }
    ]
};
```

Ожидаю я 3 объекта в коллекции, а не 6.

Никто с подобной проблемой не встречался? Из-за чего такое может происходить?

Comment: Укажите что не правильно при вызове `TestClass.getTests()`, какой результать получился и какой ожидалось, сделайте `toString()` всех объектов, посмотрите насколько они правильные в вашем случае.

Comment: @MrFylypenko Добавил информацию выше.

Comment: У Вас одинаковые элементы получаются, не знаю насколько правильно, но вместо Collection<TestParent> лучше используйте Set<TestParent>, для избежания повторяющихся элементов. Вы получили у TestClass коллекцию TestChild, без TestParent, так и должно быть?

Comment: Смена типов проблему не решает. Одинаковые элементы - это последствие неправильного sql-запроса, который генерирует Hibernate. Должен быть запрос, в которо таблица для `TestChild` присоединяется к таблице для `TestParent` с помощью `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, а тут получается декартово произведение (каждая строка одной таблицы с каждой строкой другой таблицы).  
Там где нет наследования - нет никаких проблем.  
В другом месте сегодня сказали, что с такими же сущностями всё прекрасно работает. Уже не знаю, что думать. Попробую в качестве эксперимента в этом тестовом проекте заменить Oracle на MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Экспериментальным путём выяснилось, что проблема имеет место только на СУБД Oracle. На MySQL Hibernate генерирует корректный sql-запрос:

```
SELECT tests0_.test_id AS test_id4_2_0_,
  tests0_.id           AS id1_2_0_,
  tests0_.id           AS id1_2_1_,
  tests0_.correctdt    AS correctd2_2_1_,
  tests0_.name         AS name3_2_1_,
  tests0_.test_id      AS test_id4_2_1_,
  tests0_1_.field1     AS field1_0_1_,
  CASE
    WHEN tests0_1_.id IS NOT NULL
    THEN 1
    WHEN tests0_.id IS NOT NULL
    THEN 0
  END AS clazz_1_
FROM tmp_test_parent tests0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN tmp_test_child1 tests0_1_
ON tests0_.id        =tests0_1_.id
WHERE tests0_.test_id=?
```